# Create Horizontally Scrollable UL

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navigation bar which needs an auto responsive scrollable UL list.

My HTML:

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul> 
        <li>Home </li>
        <li>Publications </li>
        <li>Exams </li>
        <li>Courses </li>
        <li>Example Text </li>
        <li>Example Text </li>
        <li>Example Text </li>
        <li>Example Text </li>
        <li>Example Text </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
   .navigation{
    background-color: darkblue;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    max-height:50px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navigation ul{
    float:right;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 50px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
.navigation ul li{
    float:left;
    color:#ffffff;
    margin-right:10px;
    text-align: center;

}
```

What am I doing wrong? It doesn't seem to be working as I want.

Comment: What is it doing? What do you want it to do? We aren't mind readers.

Comment: Yes. Can you please elaborate your question and give us a fiddle URL to check what is going wrong?

Comment: really sorry for not giving you specific idea, I was kind of new here. Will give you an URL . I have to create a Navigation Bar with Scrolling just like in an Android Menu.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5gus1nLg/  here is the fiddle I was trying to do, but it's kind of not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your Support. I found the Answer my Self. Also had got some help from Material.css here is the Exact Answer

This is what I wanted.

```css
.navigation{
    background-color: darkblue;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 max-height:50px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 overflow: hidden;
  }
.navigation ul {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 48px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.navigation ul li {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    letter-spacing: .8px;
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 80px;
}
ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation"> 
<ul>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```